# How can I parse datetimes from CSV?

Tags: python, datetime

Here is the specific line I am using line.find for:

```
Alta,"08-10-2019 16:34:42","08-10-2019 18:03:42","RESOLVIDO","roteador-assu-tely","Host indisponÃ­vel","1h 29m","NÃ£o","",""
```

Obviously, there are many other lines since its a full CSV file, but lets focus on this specific line right now.
I am using a split(',') to separate the lines and trying to generate a datetime object with it, what am I doing wrong?

```
with open(path + "zbx_problems_export.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
inicio_expediente = datetime.time(6, 40, 00)
fim_expediente = datetime.time(16, 30, 00)

for line in lines:
    if line.find('roteador-assu-tely') >= 0:
        a = line.split(',')
        data_inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime(a[1], '"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"')
        data_fim = datetime.datetime.strptime(a[2], '"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"')
        if data_inicio.time > inicio_expediente.time and data_inicio.time < fim_expediente.time and data_inicio.weekday() != 5 and data_inicio.weekday() != 6:
```

the full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScriptPythonRelatorioProto.py", line 31, in <module>
     if data_inicio.time > inicio_expediente.time and data_inicio.time < fim_expediente.time and data_inicio.weekday() != 5 and data_inicio.weekday() != 6:
AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Line 31 is the last time in the sample code posted

Comment: inicio_expediente = datetime.time(6, 40, 00),  *inicio_expediente* this is the datetime.time object,  so in your code you are using *data_inicio.time > inicio_expediente.time and data_.......*.  In which there is no *time* object for *datetime.time*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> inicio_expediente = datetime.time(6, 40, 00)
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> ```
> inicio_expediente.time
> ```

`inicio_expediente` *is* a `time` object, it doesn't have a `.time` attribute. Just remove the `.time` here.

You then have another issue here: `data_inicio.time`.
`data_inicio` is a `datetime` object and it *has* a `.time`, but that's a *method*, not a plain attribute, so that must be `data_inicio.time()`.

Comment: that worked! tyvm

Just another question before I leave, if I want to do this:

x = fim_expediente - data_inicio.time()

how can I do it?